# What is the right place to ask about a availability of a specific clustering algorithm in R or python?

Tags: discussion, support

I posted the following question on Cross Validated:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72487/flexible-upgma-in-r-or-python

and it was put on hold as off-topic after some discussion (see comments). I posted the same question to R-help and it was rejected because it was deemed inappropriate. So what would be the right place to post it? I still think it is well-defined and useful.

Comment: Q&A sites are not a good venue for this (a tool request), and I guess neither are the R mailing lists. There are R, python and stats forums and chat rooms around the internet. You could also contact the authors or the authors of papers that have cited it. If you actually know some R and python, you could get started rolling your own tool, and post questions on SO when you run into a problem you can't solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[We don't like link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/206447).

Any question asking for an implementation of an algorithm (that won't fit in an answer), will essentially be such an answer.

So, every answer will be inappropriate, thus the question itself can't very well be appropriate, can it?

(There are also reasons why questions asking for implementations that **will** fit into an answer is inappropriate - generally along the lines of not showing a sufficient attempt at solving the problem oneself)

I think this can be generalized to any Stack Exchange site, and, unfortunately we don't really provide recommendations for other websites. As a thought, a **forum** might be a better idea that a **Q&A** site (just don't ask me where to find such a forum; maybe once [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/) matures a bit, it will be the right place).

Comment: Sorry to say, but your answer does not  really help me. Did you read the last sentence: "or could give advice on the best route if we decide to implement it ourselves?" So an answer saying "I don't think there is an implementation of this algorithm yet, but the best way to do it would be..." would also be valid. The side remark of not showing sufficient attempt is a general one that can be applied to almost all questions on a Q&A site like this.

Comment: @MarkusM. Yes, "a sufficient attempt" is very subjective. Although this can be argued, I'm leaning towards too broad and/or unclear - for example, maybe some really complex data structure would give excellent performance, but if you can barely use an array, that suggestion wouldn't help much, and maybe you already considered this data structure. There's too much uncertainty. You need to at least provide enough details about your current thoughts to put us roughly on the same page. As an additional note, your question is too dependent on the article, it should generally be self-contained.

Comment: @MarkusM. Note that, while I have a fair amount of experience on Stack Overflow, I'm not entirely clued up on other sites - i.e. if your question focussed on that part, it may have been fine. So the only problem could've been that the rest of your question overshadowed that part of it. Though I doubt this is the case.

Comment: @MarkusM. Sorry, my last comment appears to have been a bit unclear. I wasn't saying it would be appropriate for [so] after editing (although there is a fair amount of R questions, so it could be), I just mentioned that that's where my experience lies, and not on [stats.se], thus my opinions regarding [stats.se] may be incorrect (everything except my last comment should be applicable to all programming [se] sites).

Comment: OK, thanks. I will repost it on SO after we started rolling our own.